# SAQL - When I dynamically create dates in SAQL and group them, I can't use the "Timeline" chart

Tags: date, einstein-analytics, charts, saql

I try to create a timeline chart for every year for products on the market that are started to sell before that year and ended to sell after that year.

To get my filtered data I filter them like I described above. Then I union my data from the different years.

All this works and I get the right data back. Also the grouping it self works, but when I try to use a timeline chart, it doesn't let me do it.

SAQL:

```
q_A = filter q by (date('start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day') in [.."3 years ago"]) && (date('end_year', 'end_month', 'end_day') in ["2 years ago"..]);
q_A = group q by 'all' full, q_A by 'all';
q_A = foreach q_A generate unique(q_A.'PlaceHolder') as 'A', toDate((date_diff("year", toDate("1969", "yyyy"), now()) - 3) * 31536000) as 'Date';

q_B = filter q by (date('start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day') in [.."2 years ago"]) && (date('end_year', 'end_month', 'end_day') in ["1 years ago"..]);
q_B = group q by 'all' full, q_B by 'all';
q_B = foreach q_B generate unique(q_B.'PlaceHolder') as 'A', toDate((date_diff("year", toDate("1969", "yyyy"), now()) - 2) * 31536000) as 'Date';

q_C = filter q by (date('start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day') in [.."1 years ago"]) && (date('end_year', 'end_month', 'end_day') in ["current year"..]);
q_C = group q by 'all' full, q_C by 'all';
q_C = foreach q_C generate unique(q_C.'PlaceHolder') as 'A', toDate((date_diff("year", toDate("1969", "yyyy"), now()) - 1) * 31536000) as 'Date';

q_D = filter q by (date('start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day') in [.."current year"]) && (date('end_year', 'end_month', 'end_day') in ["1 year ahead"..]);
q_D = group q by 'all' full, q_C by 'all';
q_D = foreach q_C generate unique(q_C.'PlaceHolder') as 'A', toDate((date_diff("year", toDate("1969", "yyyy"), now())) * 31536000) as 'Date';

result = union q_A, q_B, q_C, q_D;
q_new = group result by 'Date';
q_new = foreach q_new generate 'Date' as 'Date', sum('A') as 'Sum';
```

Results:

[image]

Every help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with SAQL a lot of different ways, but the only thing that worked was that I used Recipies and calculated for every row for every year, if it was on the market. Lets call them "IP_[YEAR]"

Then I ordered it by StartDate and summed every "IP_[YEAR]" up.
I created a new column and summed all "IP_[YEAR]" columns to one "sum" column together. Then I hid the "IP_[YEAR]" columns and it worked.

Here the SAQL to the resolution:

```
q = filter q by (date('start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day') in ["2 years ago".."8 years ahead"];
result = group q by 'start_year';
result = foreach result generate q.'start_year' as 'start_year', sum(q.'IP_2019') as 'B', sum(q.'IP_2020') as 'C', sum(q.'IP_2021') as 'D', sum(q.'IP_2022') as 'E', sum(q.'IP_2023') as 'F', sum(q.'IP_2024') as 'G', sum(q.'IP_2025') as 'H', sum(q.'IP_2026') as 'I', sum(q.'IP_2027') as 'J', sum(q.'IP_2028') as 'K', sum(q.'IP_2008') as 'L', sum(q.'IP_20091') as 'M', sum(q.'IP_2010') as 'N', sum(q.'IP_2011') as 'O', sum(q.'IP_2012') as 'P', sum(q.'IP_2013') as 'Q', sum(q.'IP_2014') as 'R', sum(q.'IP_2015') as 'S', sum(q.'IP_2016') as 'T', sum(q.'IP_2017') as 'U', sum(q.'IP_2018') as 'V';
result = foreach result generate 'start_year' as 'start_year', 'B' as 'B', 'C' as 'C', 'D' as 'D', 'E' as 'E', 'F' as 'F', 'G' as 'G', 'H' as 'H', 'I' as 'I', 'J' as 'J', 'K' as 'K', 'L' as 'L', 'M' as 'M', 'N' as 'N', 'O' as 'O', 'P' as 'P', 'Q' as 'Q', 'R' as 'R', 'S' as 'S', 'T' as 'T', 'U' as 'U', 'V' as 'V', ((((((((((((((((((('B' + 'C') + 'D') + 'E') + 'F') + 'G') + 'H') + 'I') + 'J') + 'K') + 'L') + 'M') + 'N') + 'O') + 'P') + 'Q') + 'R') + 'S') + 'T') + 'U') + 'V' as 'A';
result = order result by 'start_year' asc;
```

Maybe it will help somebody.